# Create a ZIP file without entries touching the disk?

Tags: c#, zip

I'm trying to create a program that has the capability of creating a zipped package containing files based on user input.

I don't need any of those files to be written to the hard drive before they're zipped, as that would be unnecessary, so how do I create these files without actually writing them to the hard drive, and then have them zipped?

I'm using DotNetZip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the documentation [here](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples), specifically the example called "Create a zip using content obtained from a stream":

```
 using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
  {
    ZipEntry e= zip.AddEntry("Content-From-Stream.bin", "basedirectory", StreamToRead);
    e.Comment = "The content for entry in the zip file was obtained from a stream";
    zip.AddFile("Readme.txt");
    zip.Save(zipFileToCreate);
  }
```

If your files are not already in a stream format, you'll need to convert them to one.  You'll probably want to use a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) for that.

Answer (score 0):

I use SharpZipLib, but if DotNetZip can do everything against a basic System.IO.Stream, then yes, just feed it a MemoryStream to write to.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to the hard disk shouldn't be something avoid because it's unnecessary. That's backwards. If it's not a requirement that the entire zipping process is done in memory then avoid it by writing to the hard disk.

The hard disk is better suited for storing large amounts of data than memory is. If by some chance your zip file ends up being around a gigabyte in size your application could croak or at least cause a system slowdown. If you write directly to the hard drive the zip could be several gigabytes in size without causing an issue.

Comment: If the data is already in memory then there is no point writing it to the hard drive only to read it back again so you can zip it.  As such your statement "Writing to the hard disk shouldn't be something avoid because it's unnecessary." is incorrect.

Comment: The zip file will never exceed around 1 megabyte and can contain upwards of 200 files (relatively small ones), so writing all of those to the hard drive and then zipping them would be inefficient.

Comment: @Trisped - Sure there is. That way you don't use up large amounts of memory. There's a reason chunking is such a common pattern when dealing with files just like there's a reason chunks are usually only around 8kb.

Comment: @Ipquarx - It's not inefficient. Your decision to keep it all in memory will most likely work fine but your reluctance to use the hard drive is a misconception you should re-evaluate.

Comment: @SpencerRuport - I'm not sure of that.  Avoiding the hard disk, which generally is the slowest part of a system, seems like a good idea to me.  Always provided you have sufficient knowledge of your problem domain that you can be reasonably sure that you won't suddenly end up with a multi-GB file that clobbers your system, and you don't need an intermediate backup incase the rest of the processing fails.

Comment: @Bobson - For specific scenarios I would discourage using the hard disk but it seems to me that *most* of the time the write delay is going to be fairly insignificant. Not only do you have to have the knowledge that the files themselves won't grow beyond a manageable size but that this code won't be susceptible to a DoS attack where requests for this code to run are flooded to the system. That said, I don't expect everyone to agree this is the way to go I just felt it was worthwhile to offer a contrasting opinion on the matter.

Comment: @SpencerRuport - Contrasting viewpoints are always worth mentioning.  I don't agree (for certain scenarios anyway), but that's why it's contrasting.  +1.